# $elemMatch in Casbah

Tags: scala, casbah

For this document structure:

`_id: 1, records : [{n : "Name", v: "Will"}]`

How can I perform a `$elemMatch` Mongo shell query from Casbah?

`db.coll.find( {records : {$elemMatch : {n: : "Name", v : "Will"} } } )`

I tried this from the Casbah code's test [directory](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-query/src/test/scala/DSLCoreOperatorsSpec.scala), but I got 0 results.

```
var builder = MongoDBObject()
val elemMatch = "records" $elemMatch (MongoDBObject
                                      ("n" -> "Name", "v" -> "Will"))
builder = builder ++ elemMatch
collection.find(builder)
```

I'm getting a type mismatch on the `collection.find(builder)` line.

**EDIT** Provided more text for compile-time error.

```
[error]  found   : collection.CursorType
[error]     (which expands to)  com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCursor
[error]  required: Int
[error]         collection.find(MongoDBObject(), elemMatch)
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
```

Full gist - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/6817354

Comment: What mongo version and casbah version are you using?

Comment: Mongo 2.4.6 & Casbah 2.6.3

Comment: doh - I forgot to put `in` at the end of my scalatest method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a little extra wrapping there thats not needed like the `builder` - heres a cleaned up example:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
val coll = MongoClient()("test")("testB")
coll.drop()

coll += MongoDBObject("records" -> List(MongoDBObject("n" -> "Name", "v" -> "Will"), 
                                        MongoDBObject("n" -> "age", "v" -> 100)))

val elemMatch = "records" $elemMatch MongoDBObject("n" -> "Name", "v" -> "Will")
coll.find(elemMatch).count
```